# How to clone easeljs bitmap which has filters on it that been cached.

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

...

```
let blurFilter = new createjs.BlurFilter(blurX, blurY, blurQuality);
bitmap.filters = [blurFilter];
bitmap.cache(0, -blurY, this.width, this.height + blurY);
```

...

> bitmap.clone() doesn't clone the cached bitmap with filters. It only clones the original file image.
>
> I don't want to apply filters twice as it will take lot of time and resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since DisplayObjects don't clone their caches (which would probably create some unexpected results), you could simply assign the cache yourself:

```
var bmp2 = bmp1.clone();
bmp2.cacheCanvas = bmp1.cacheCanvas;
bmp2.bitmapCache = bmp2.bitmapCache; // Also required for version 1.0+
```

Note that will make both instances update if you updated either of the bitmaps using `updateCache()`.

A way I use a lot is to simply make the cacheCanvas the source of new Bitmaps. If you are using a scale factor, you will have to accommodate it.

```
var bmp2 = new createjs.Bitmap(bmp2.cacheCanvas);
```

This approach will *not* work if you are using WebGL caches (via StageGL).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Lanny :) It worked. Btw, what is the calculation for caching exactly the bounds of the blurfilter result? because it isn't very clear to me at the official tutorial... will this always cache perfectly the filter result? bitmap.cache(-blurX, -blurY, beforeBlurBitmapWidth + blurX, beforeBlurBitmapHeight + blurY); Thanks again